# Jmeter RTE Plugin Connection timed out: connect

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, mainframe, 3270

I'm trying to use Jmeter RTE Plugin to make mainframe tests.
Using a pconn or wc3270, it`s connects good but trying to record or using an existent JMX file, i'm getting a connection exception.

There is any other configuration that I need to do?

```
com.blazemeter.jmeter.rte.core.exceptions.RteIOException: Communication error wit server: 192.168.2.2
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.rte.core.listener.ExceptionHandler.throwAnyPendingError(ExceptionHandler.java:41)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.rte.protocols.tn3270.Tn3270Client.connect(Tn3270Client.java:159)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.rte.sampler.RTESampler.buildClient(RTESampler.java:617)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.rte.sampler.RTESampler.sample(RTESampler.java:516)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at com.bytezone.dm3270.streams.TerminalServer.run(TerminalServer.java:48)
    ... 1 more
```

I already tried; reinstall jmeter, java, get a jmeter working installation and script but nothing fixed that issue.

[Configs of wc3270 and rte plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az8Yj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back on this thread to share the solution and add an information.
My jmeter test it`s connecting through VPN connection and the problem it was Java trying to use IPv4 over IPv6 for IPv4 connections.
**resolution**: setx _JAVA_OPTIONS ***-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true***

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we're not able to help without seeing your wc3270 and [RTE Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin#a-config-element-rte-config) (or [RTE Recorder](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin#a-config-element-rte-config)) configuration details.

The exception means that JMeter cannot connect to the host `192.168.2.2` on the given port so I would recommend double checking that you can reach that host using [telnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/telnet) or equivalent.

You can also [enable debug logging](https://github.com/Blazemeter/RTEPlugin#contributing) and see whether [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) contains any clues.

And finally you can check out [Testing Mainframe Environments Using Open Source Tools](https://info.blazemeter.com/testing-mainframe-environments-using-open-source-tools) and cross check it with your setup, maybe you're missing something obvious.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I`ve attached the configs. Strange to note that config`s it`s working on Mac from a team member.